# XAMPP Manager-OSX Error on Mojave Upgrade

Tags: xampp, macos-mojave

Just upgraded Mac to MacOS Mojave 10.14.  Running XAMPP 7.2.5.  On startup, XAMPP Manager-OSX generates error message and is now missing button labels.

Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Comment: I too add same issue while using xampp on new macos Majove, Please share if you have got any solution.
Thanks

Comment: I am unaware of any solutions to this issue.  It's been reported, with screenshot, on StackOverflow at:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543584/xampp-7-2-10-0-macos-mojave-no-button-label-are-visible  and on XAMPP at https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=77475