# XAMPP 7.2.10-0 macOS Mojave - No button label are visible

Tags: xampp, macos-mojave

I installed the new version of `XAMPP` for Apple Mac OS, that is 7.2.10-0. When I open the manager-osx the label of button aren't visible. Below is a photo of my manager-osx. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with the button *text* not the functionality. You can still click on the buttons to function the features. You just need to know which button is meant for what.

You can check the picture attached for the buttons with texts.

[image: Xampp for Mac with button text]

Comment: According to me the problem is not the button functionality but the text hidden. Who can resolve the problem?

Comment: As @Elias Bellido said, it is a bug in XAMPP. I hope they will update it in the next version :-)

Answer (score 7):

at the moment please turn on the services from terminal using this command : sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. Can I ask you if there is a way to see the source code, for example on github, and correct the bug?

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Xampp will solve this problem!

You can download it at the link below:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Mac%20OS%20X/7.2.11/

Comment: I can confirm that 7.2.11 is a normal version and not XAMPP-VM

Answer (score 1):

You can run from the terminal as follows:

`-> cd /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles`

`-> sudo ./xampp start`

To check on MYSQL status:

`-> mysql status -u [username] -p [password]`

To stop:

`-> sudo ./xampp stop`

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same issue after updating to Mojave. Try uninstalling the older version and install using the link given below. It works

https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.2.12/xampp-osx-7.2.12-0-installer.dmg

Comment: Uninstalling xampp will wipe out your mysql databases, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem so I just started using the terminal as a way to start the server